# Signal Must Assert While Other Signal Is Asserted

Tags: system-verilog, assertion, system-verilog-assertions

I have a situation where a signal in a design must assert for at least one cycle while another signal is asserted for at least X cycles.

Desired Results:

Pass:
[pass example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xe7L.png)

Pass:
[pass example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfRIK.png)

Pass:
[pass example 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3N0h.png)

Fail:
[fail example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1D1f.png)

I would like to write a property to check for this using SVA, essentially capturing that between the `posedge` and `negedge` of `sig_1`, `sig_2` must have both `$rose()` and `$fell()`.

I have tried something like...

```
property prop_sig_2_while_sig_1;
    @(posedge clk)
        $rose(sig_1) ##[0:$] $rose(sig_2) ##[0:$] $fell(sig_2) ##[0:$] $fell(sig_1);
endproperty : prop_sig_2_while_sig_1
```

but unfortunately, that did not work as desired.

Is there a simple and effective way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want is

```
property prop_sig_2_while_sig_1;
    @(posedge clk) $rose(sig_1) |-> sig_1 throughout sig_2[->1];
endproperty
```

This gives you your desired results.